# How would I write a function that would display a data frame of the statistics of a specific season? (NEW TO CODING)

Tags: r, function

I have downloaded data from the last three seasons of the English Premiere League and would like to create a basic function that would simply allow me to input a season such as "2021/22" and have the function return a data frame of that seasons statistics. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide further information, please? Without knowing about the structure of your dataset or a code example it's quite difficult to help you. In any case, have a look at the `dplyr` library (part of `tidyverse`) and its [filter() function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to input data (eg. 2021/22) in the console with the readline() function. The answer will be interpreted as a character string (eg. "2021/22"). Assign that answer to a variable, var.

```
`var <- readline("Ask your question.")`
```

You can use if/else functions to determine what happens based upon that answer. See this tutorial :

https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/if-else-statement/

```
`if (var == "your_answer") {print(your_dataframe)}`
```

The answer to the readline() will have to match the if statement exactly.

I'm also new to r and coding. I'd recommend doing a free EdX course or auditing a Coursera course to get some basics and then searching the forums.

If you want more specific code advice, you need to provide your code, the output you hope to get and what you've tried already (so people know they aren't just doing your work for you!). Those are generally good tips for forum etiquette in the coding world.

Hope that helps, good luck! If others respond they are probably more experienced and I'd disregard my answer, but it might get the ball rolling.